# Cannot get a good jQuery ajax code for this

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have made a piece of jQuery code that has been made to dynamicaly append a new textfield.
And it will also check the amount of fields.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>

<head>
<style type="text/css">

    fieldset { 
        margin-bottom: 1em; 
    }

    input { 
        display: block; 
        margin-bottom: .25em; 
    }

    #print-output {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .print-output-line {
        white-space: pre;
        padding: 5px;
        font-family: monaco, monospace;
        font-size: .7em;
    }

    .enter {
        padding-bottom: 15px;72-96027-0008

    }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="doIt ();">

<form>
    <div id="fields">
        <input id="input_'+ i +'" type="text" name="barcodes[]" class="target" /><span id="status_'+ i +'"></span><br />
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function doIt ()
    {
        var i = $('input').size() + 1;

        $("input:last").focus();
        $("input:last").keypress (function (e)
        {
            if (e.which == 13)
            {
                e.preventDefault();

                $("#input_'+ i +'").change(function(){

                var barcode = $("input_'+ i +'").val
                if(barcode.length > 0){
                    $("#status_'+ i +'").html('');

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "text.txt",
                        data: "barcode="+ username,
                        success: function(server_response){
                            $("#status_'+ i +'").ajaxComplete(function(event, request){
                                if(server_response == '0'){
                                    $("#status_'+ i +'").html('<font color="red">On bekdende Barcode. probeer het opnieuw.</font>');
                                }else if(server_response == '1'){
                                    $("#status_'+ i +'").html('');

                                    $("#fields").append ('<div class="enter" id="input_'+ i +'"><input type="text" name="barcodes[]"  class="target" /><a href="#" onclick="verwijder (\'' + i + '\')">Delete</a><span id="status"></span></div><div id="error"></div>');
                                    $("#nItems").html("Er zijn " + (i - 1) + " items gescant");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
                doIt ();
            });
        }
    });

    doIt ();

    function verwijder (i)
    {
        $("#input_" + i).remove ();
    }
</script>

<span id="nItems">Er zijn nog geen items gescant</span>

</body>

</html>
```

But now I want it to check if the input in the fields exists.
And it has to say if it doesn't exsists.
I have tried alot and nothing doesn't works yet.

Help would be apreciated.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "the input in the fields"? Do you mean you need to check whether the inputs have any value?

Comment: when i put a 1 in the field it has to be checked if there is a 1 in the database. and so on

Comment: Why is your input id _literally_ "input_' + i +'"? Seems like you're trying to put a dynamic id in there, but this is not how that's going to work...

Comment: yeah - check code for misplaced quotes.... what Sander pointed out should probably just be double quotes araound the + i + ....and a number in the html. Also the value assigning of barcode seems to be missing () after .val

Comment: i know  i`m farly new to jquery and espacialy ajax. and the firts time to alk for the awnser online. but at this moment i can use al the help i can get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'HEAD',
    url: 'link to chek with db',
    success: function() {
        alert('Item found.');
    },  
    error: function() {
        alert('Item not found.');
    }
});
```